# haproxy pointing to a specific host

Tags: haproxy

So I have an instance in which I need haproxy's backend to use the hostname instead of the IP address. In this case we have a URL that the 4th level domain is a hash specific to our account with the domain, however the IP address is a shared IP address for many of these accounts. The way I have been looking at it is as a named vhost on the backed. When I set it up it fails because the backend server does not recognize the traffic as going to the proper vhost. This is what I have

```
frontend findtext
  bind xxx.xxx.xxx.206:80 
  mode http
  default_backend findtext

backend findtext
  balance source
  http-request set-header Host xxxxxxxx.search.serialssolutions.com
  mode http
  option httplog
  server xxxxxxxx.search.serialssolutions.com 216.147.213.8:80 check
```

Anyone able to help me figure out how to set this up so the back end server will see the traffic as pointing to the host instead of the IP address?

Comment: Try it in `tcp` mode?

Comment: For hostname instead of IP try `resolvers` (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#5.3). Or just put your hostname instead of IP if you are sure it won't change. Haproxy's docs say it resolves hostnames on startup.

Answer (score 0):

My above statement actually worked, but my haproxy instance was looking at the wrong cfg file.